# A Python one liner? if x in y, do x

Tags: python, ruby

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
number = 1
```

Can I write the following on one line?

```py
if number in numbers:
    print number
```

Using the style of ruby:

```rb
puts number if numbers.include?(number)
```

I have tried:

```py
print number if number in numbers
```

But the syntax is invalid.

Comment: FWIW, another way to do it in Ruby is Array intersection: `puts numbers & [number]`. I don't know if there is a simple equivalent in Python.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9345250/988071) thread.

Comment: @MarkThomas I didn't know that. Nice ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python is Python, Ruby is Ruby. My advice is not to try writing one in the other.

Python does not have Ruby's / Perl's "postfix if", and the Pythonic way to write this is the one you've already got.

But if you really must, this will work:

```
if number in numbers: print number
```

It is against the official style guide, [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), though:

> - Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.
>
>   Yes:
>
>   ```
>   if foo == 'blah':
>       do_blah_thing()
>   do_one()
>   do_two()
>   do_three()
>   ```
>
>   Rather not:
>
>   ```
>   if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
>   do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
>   ```

Comment: thanks, I was just checking there wasn't a little trick I was missing.  is it considered 'bad form' to write it in the way that your answer gives?

Answer (score 8):

The python syntax is `yes_value if test else no_value`. With optional parentheses for clarity, you can say this:

```
print "Searching...", ("Found it" if n in numbers else "Not found")
```

I agree, the syntax is incredibly unintuitive. Even C conditional expressions are easier to read.

Comment: Your facts are fine but I find your opinion appalling.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
if number in numbers: print number
```

Or, if you are using Python 3:

```
if number in numbers: print(number)
```

IMHO less readability so I use the two liner.

Answer (score 2):

If you add *else ""* to the end of your original code you will get a working construct in Python 2.7:

```
print number if number in numbers else ""
```

If number is in numbers then it will be printed.  Otherwise, an empty string is printed.

But as others have noted, if you really don't want the print statement executed at all, you have to go with:

```
if number in numbers: print number
```