# Print "Foo" if an element is in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have tried:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> x = 1
>>> x in l and lambda: print("Foo")
    x in l && print "Horray"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

A bit of googling revealed that `print` is a statement in `python2` whereas it's a function in `python3`. But, I have tried the above snipped in `python3` and it throws SyntaxError exception.

Any idea on how can I do it in **one line**? (Readability or google programming practice is not an issue here)

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344345/a-python-one-liner-if-x-in-y-do-x) has been asked a couple of hours  ago.

Comment: But, I want to do it the [short-circuiting way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: `if x in l` *does* short-circuit, because one it `x` matches the first element in `l` which is equal to it, it doesn't evaluate the rest of the elements

Comment: He wants to short-circuit the outer boolean expression, the `and` part. Like `x in l and foobar() or barbaz()`

Comment: @Irfy I misunderstood OP's intent. Your answer is what he wants then.

Comment: Regardless of the problem with `print`, the error you're getting is about `&&`, which may **not** be substituted for `and` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` creates, well a lambda. It needs to be *called* to execute it. You cannot do this that way, because Python doesn't allow statements in this context, only expressions (including function calls).

To make `print` a function in Python 2.x, try:

```
from __future__ import print_function
x in l and print('foo')
```

Be wary though. If you try:

```
x in l and print('foo') or print('bar')
```

it won't work, because print returns `None`, so the first `and` expression is False, so both `print`s will be executed. In Python 3.x you don't need the import.

If you won't have complex short-circuiting (i.e. just one `and` or `or`), or you know your functions or expressions won't surprise the short-circuiting logic, there's nothing wrong with the code. Otherwise, try the non-short-circuiting 1-liner:

```
print('foo') if x in l else print('bar')
```

This form is recommended only if the probability/expectation of the conditional to be True is *vastly* higher than being False. Otherwise, plain good-old `if-else` is the way to go.

Comment: Refactoring to `print('foo' if x in l else 'bar')` is certainly saner.

Answer (score 6):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
x = 1
if x in l: print "Foo"
```

I'm not being a smart ass, this is the way to do it in **one line**. Or, if you're using Python3:

```
if x in l: print("Foo")
```

Comment: But, I want to do it the [short-circuiting way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: +1 for the right way to do it. I don't know what this infatuation people have with one-liners, I can only assume they have a shortage of newline characters in their environments :-)

Comment: It's possible, though I wouldn't recommend it, see my answer.

Comment: Python was made to be simple and readable. Both of these attributes are present in the code I posted and unless there's a valid reason to use short-circuit evaluation you're just writing ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the shortcomings of print as a statement in Python2.x using `from __future__ import print_function` is the first step. Then the following all work:

```
x in l and (lambda: print("yes"))()       # what an overkill!
(x in l or print("no")) and print("yes")  # note the order, print returns None
print("yes") if x in l else print("no")   # typical A if Cond else Y
print("yes" if x in l else "no")          # a more condensed form
```

For even more fun, if you're into this, you can consider this - prints and returns True or False, depending on the `x in l` condition (to get the False I used the double not):

```
def check_and_print(x, l):
    return x in l and not print("yes") or not not print("no")
```

That was ugly. To make the print transparent, you could define 2 other version
of print, which return True or False. This could actually be useful for logging:

```
def trueprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    return True

def falseprint(*args, **kwargs):
    return not trueprint(*args, **kwargs)

result = x in l and trueprint("yes") or falseprint("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to print something different in both true and false cases, use a conditional **expression** to create the value to print: `print ('foo' if x in l else 'bar')`.
2. If you just want a function in Python 2 that outputs, you can try `sys.stdout.write` (after you first `import sys` of course), but keep in mind that this is nowhere near as flexible; here you're treating the standard output as a file-like object (which it is).
3. `lambda` almost certainly buys you nothing here.
4. Using and-or chaining tricks is incredibly un-Pythonic. The fact that people struggled with these hacks anyway, knowing how awful they were, was exactly why those conditional expressions from point 1 were added to the language. There was a **lot** of discussion regarding syntax.